# parameter of fixture_file_upload went to String class in request spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

The following code produces some wrongs.

#### spec/rails_helper.rb

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include ActionDispatch::TestProcess

  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  ...
end
```

#### spec/request/api/v1/images_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe 'Images', type: :request do
  describe 'POST api/v1/images' do
    it 'should have status :created' do
      post api_v1_images_path(content: fixture_file_upload('test.jpg', 'image/jpeg'), position: 0), nil , nil
      # #<Rack::Test::UploadedFile:0x007f92beb9cfc8 @content_type={:content_type=>"image/jpeg"}, @original_filename="test.jpg", @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/qv/8k9_kbs52w5ddhb1ph41xngh0000gn/T/test.jpg20140922-11520-1co5l19>>

      expect(response).to have_http_status(:created)
    end
  end
end
```

#### app/controllers/api/v1/images_controller.rb

```
def create
  puts params[:content].class #=> String
  # String..!? What's going on..!?
  #
  # I'd like to pass upload rspec with carrierwave.
  # Creating model with uploader by params[:content] will cause null value of image attributes of model.
end
```

Object id is same, but attributes are disappeared.. What's happen?

#### Gemfile.lock

```
rails (4.1.5)
  actionmailer (= 4.1.5)
  actionpack (= 4.1.5)
  actionview (= 4.1.5)
  activemodel (= 4.1.5)
  activerecord (= 4.1.5)
  activesupport (= 4.1.5)
  bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
  railties (= 4.1.5)
  sprockets-rails (~> 2.0)
rspec (3.1.0)
  rspec-core (~> 3.1.0)
  rspec-expectations (~> 3.1.0)
  rspec-mocks (~> 3.1.0)
rspec-core (3.1.0)
  rspec-support (~> 3.1.0)
rspec-expectations (3.1.0)
  diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
  rspec-support (~> 3.1.0)
rspec-mocks (3.1.0)
  rspec-support (~> 3.1.0)
rspec-rails (3.1.0)
  actionpack (>= 3.0)
  activesupport (>= 3.0)
  railties (>= 3.0)
  rspec-core (~> 3.1.0)
  rspec-expectations (~> 3.1.0)
  rspec-mocks (~> 3.1.0)
  rspec-support (~> 3.1.0)
rspec-support (3.1.0)
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do... and what's going wrong... what did you expect the output of `params[:content]` to be and why? have you considered actually trying to access the attributes on it (eg `puts params[:content].original_filename` to check that it's actually there (just not showing up in the puts line)?

Comment: I'd like to pass upload rspec with carrierwave. Create model with uploader by `params[:content]` will cause null value of image attributes of model.

Comment: OMG, I found `params[:content].class` is `String` ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I misused post method...

Before:
`post api_v1_images_path(content: fixture_file_upload('test.jpg', 'image/jpeg'), position: 0), nil , nil`

After:
`post api_v1_images_path, {content: fixture_file_upload('test.jpg', 'image/jpeg'), position: 0}, nil`

"After" passed spec.

Comment: Could you expound on what the problem was? I can find the page documenting the post method to know what the extra parameters are.

Answer (score 2):

Rails 5:

Before:

`post api_v1_images_path params: { content: fixture_file_upload('test.jpg', 'image/jpeg'), position: 0 }`

After:

`post api_v1_images_path {}, params: { content: fixture_file_upload('test.jpg', 'image/jpeg'), position: 0 }`